# No route matches, form_tag ,ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-post, rails-routing

routes.rb file:

```
get "dcrelations/create" 
get "dcrelations/destroy"
resources :dcrelations
match 'derelations/create' => 'dcrelations#create'
match 'derelations/destroy' => 'dcrelations#destroy'
```

form file:

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "dcrelations", :action => "create", :method => "post") do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= hidden_field_tag(:clinic_id, @clinic.clinic_id) %>
    <%= label_tag(:doctor_id, "doctor_id: ") %><br />
    <%= number_field_tag(:doctor_id) %>
  </div>
  <%= submit_tag("Add Doctor") %>
<% end %>
```

render form file:

```
<%= render 'shared/dcrelation_form' %>
```

controller file:

```
def create
  @dcrelation = Dcrelation.new(params[:clinic_id],params[:doctor_id])
  if @dcrelation.save
    flash[:success] = "doctor added!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'clinic/show'
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @clinic }
  end
end
```

error page

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/dcrelations/create"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

rake routes

```
dcrelations_create  GET /dcrelations/create(.:format)  dcrelations#create
dcrelations_destroy GET /dcrelations/destroy(.:format) dcrelations#destroy
    dcrelations GET    /dcrelations(.:format)          dcrelations#index
                POST   /dcrelations(.:format)          dcrelations#create
 new_dcrelation GET    /dcrelations/new(.:format)      dcrelations#new
edit_dcrelation GET    /dcrelations/:id/edit(.:format) dcrelations#edit
     dcrelation GET    /dcrelations/:id(.:format)      dcrelations#show
                PUT    /dcrelations/:id(.:format)      dcrelations#update
                DELETE /dcrelations/:id(.:format)      dcrelations#destroy
           root        /                               onedoc#home
         create        /create(.:format)               dcrelations#create
        destroy        /destroy(.:format)              dcrelations#destroy
```

guys, i just want to use form_tag to update the db.
I got stucked by this error and have been searching for few hours.
Appreciated for all your help!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `action => :create` from your form_tag declaration.

Per your raked routes, the only route you have for a POST to resolve to dcrelations#create is to the URI `/dcrelations(.:format)`

Comment: Let's right answer!!! thank you so much. Could you tell me why? why do we dont need action:create, but the programmer know it is for method create, because I have a destroy method as well.

Comment: The Rails routing guide does a good job explaining why this behavior works the way it does, pay special attention to section 2.2 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html